# SwiftUI Dynamic Search Component Rendered Underneath neighbors

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Ive got a custom search component that takes user input and displays matching results.

```swift
struct SearchListView: View {
    @Binding var value:String
    @Binding var options: [String]
    @Binding var isOpen:Bool 

    @State private var searchText = ""
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    
    var filteredOptions: [String] {
        if self.searchText.isEmpty {
            return options
        } else {
            return options.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
        }
    }
    
    private func submit(val:String){
        if options.contains(val){
            self.value = val
            self.searchText = val
            self.isOpen = false
            self.isFocused = false
        } else {
            print("submitted value was not in the list")
            print(val)
            self.searchText = val
            self.isOpen = true
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding(10)
                        .focused(self.$isFocused)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.isOpen = true
                            self.searchText = ""
                        }
                        .onChange(of: searchText) { _ in
                            self.isOpen = true
                        }
                        .onSubmit {
                            self.submit(val: self.searchText)
                        }
                    
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        withAnimation{
                            self.isOpen.toggle()
                            self.isFocused = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Group {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.InfluxerGray)
                                .frame(width: 2, height: 30)
                                .padding(.leading, 7)
                                .padding(.trailing, 7)
                            
                            Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.Text)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .padding(.trailing, 10)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.InfluxerGray, lineWidth: 1))
                
                if(self.isOpen && self.isFocused){
                    VStack {
                        ScrollView {
                            LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
                                ForEach(filteredOptions, id: \.self) { option in
                                    Button {
                                        self.submit(val: option)
                                    } label: {
                                        HStack {
                                            Text(option)
                                                .font(Font.headline)
                                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            
                                            Spacer()
                                            
                                            if self.value == option {
                                                Circle()
                                                    .fill(Color.SelectedGreen)
                                                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                                                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                Circle()
                                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1)
                                                    .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                                                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                                            }
                                        }
                                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.black)) // Ensure this background doesn't cover the entire screen
                        .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2) // Adjust the height of the ScrollView
                    }
                }
            }
        }.background(Rectangle().fill(Color.blue))
    }
}
```

```swift
VStack() {
                    
                    Text("College")
                        .font(Font.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                    SearchListView(value: self.$user.college, options:self.$schools, isOpen:self.$schoolOpened)
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width - 70)
                        .padding(.bottom, self.schoolOpened ? 100 : 0)
                    
                    Text("Sport")
                        .font(Font.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 15)
                    SearchListView(value: self.$user.sport , options:self.$sports, isOpen:self.$sportOpened)
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width - 70)
                        .padding(.bottom, self.sportOpened ? 100 : 0)
}
```

When I use two of them however, as siblings, the options list that shows up is underneath. [image]

Im new to swift (coming form HTML/Web), so if someone can explain how I can make it so that the siblings are "pushed down" when their siblings grow in vertical height.